# Why Excel is showing this error when I try to do data validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do data validation in Excel and I've done it before but for some reason now this error is showing up.
[This is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8kbx.png)

Here is the source table for it
[Source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3yMZ.png)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Data validation list doesn't support multi column. Use single column.

Answer (score 1):

When using "Lists" for data validation in excel spreadsheets, you must specify a range either horizontal (A1:J1) or vertical (A1:A10). This means you are not will be able to specify a "Matrix range" (A1:J10), and that is why the warning message says: "The list must refer to a single row or column (no a matrix).

Example of a wrong range selection:
[Example of a wrong range selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDWtm.png)

Example of a correct range selection:
[Example of a correct range selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkFK2.png)

Answer (score 0):

It means that the data validation list must be a one-way list (single column range or single row range), or a delimited list like this: A, B, AB, CD.

Range("A1:A10") Valid

Range("A1:D1") Valid

Hope it's helpful

Range("A1:C10") Invalid